# android imageview ontouch show high resolution image

Tags: android, imageview

I have 3 images as thumbnail.
I want to allow user touch the image to see the high resolution image.
I tried to do this way:
I added 4 imageviews. 3 of them is associated with thumbnail image. I want to reuse the last imageview for showing the high resolution image.

```
          imgBitmapHigh = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis1);
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    imageViewFull.setImageBitmap(imgBitmapHigh );
                    imageViewFull.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageViewFull.bringToFront();

                    return false;
                }

                });
```

The problem I face is, I dont know how to pass the imgBitmapHigh of high resoluton image to onTouchListner. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom Toast view in which you can use images view with high resolution.